# How could I convert this random generator from JS to Python version

Tags: javascript, python

The javascript version:

```
Math.floor((1+Math.random())*65536).toString(16).substring(1)
```

The python version what I can come up with:

```
def _get_number_in_hex():
    tmp = int((1+random.random())*65536)
    return hex(tmp)[3:]
```

Is there any thing wrong about my Python version, it's supposed to be the same as the js version .

Comment: Since some javascript programmers don't know anything about python and some python programmers don't know anything about javascript(yeah...I really don't know anything about javascript), what about explain what do these versions do and what's your expect output?

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother trying to copy that garbage generator. Use random bytes and encode them as hex (if that's what you want)

```
import os
os.urandom(4).encode('hex')[0:4]
os.urandom(4).encode('hex')[0:4]
os.urandom(4).encode('hex')[0:4]
os.urandom(4).encode('hex')[0:4]
```

Output

```
0b93
72f8
7ec0
1204
```

Comment: so - not working in recent python versions. Tried  `str(os.urandom(4)).encode().hex()[0:4]` but it is not the same. Update here would be great :)

Comment: this works though `str(os.urandom(4)).encode().hex()[5:9]` XD

Answer (score 0):

Loved the fact that there was an answer to this, as I had the exact same challenge. Seems the syntax has changed slightly in the newer python versions however, so posting it here for the next guy or girl;

```
str(os.urandom(4)).encode().hex()[5:9]
```